# jQuery Validate: How to post() after form is valid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

this works:

```
 $('#contestform').on('submit', function(e) {
     $.post( '/', $(this).serialize(), function(response){
    console.log(response);
},'json' );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

and this works

```
jQuery("#contestform").validate();
```

But I cant figure out how to get them to work together.  I want the stuff from the top code to happen only if the submit is clicked and the form is valid.  I've tried the stuff from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions but I guess i dont get it.  I had it sorta working at one point, but you had to click the submit twice.

One thing is, if I can help it, I want to keep the post() stuff in a separate function, as the two parts will be coming from different parts of the php.

**edit 1**
tried this, not working (under the form)
(by not working, i mean that it is submitting normally, not ajax)

```
function postForm(e) {
     jQuery.post( '/', $(this).serialize(),   function(response){
    console.log(response);
},'json' );
    e.preventDefault();
}
jQuery("#contestform").validate({submitHandler: postForm});
```

**edit2**
Well, I got it working with the jQuery.Form plugin
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit
Still, I'd like to know what I was doing wrong in my code above.

```
function  showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){
    console.log(responseText);
}
var soptions = { 
        success: showResponse ,
        dataType: 'json'
        };

jQuery("#contestform").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
     jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit(soptions);
        return false; // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to the submitHandler function is not a jQuery event it is the form DOM object.  So

1. your code will throw an error when you call e.preventDefault();
2. call $(form).serialize(), not $(this).serialize()

to get your edit1 working do this

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("form").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.post('/your_url/',
            $(form).serialize(), function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }, 'json');
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

or keeping the the postForm function separate

```
<script>
$(function () {

    function postForm(form) {
        $.post('/your_url/',
            $(form).serialize(),
            function (response) { console.log(response); }, 
            'json');
    }

    jQuery("form").validate({
        submitHandler : postForm
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function postForm (e) {
    $.post(...);
}
jQuery("#contestform").validate({submitHandler: postForm});
```

Comment: please see edited question, not working, but I probly dont have my function set up correct